# LaTeX - ConTeXt converter or there and back again:)

Tags: fonts, memoir, context, typography, context-mkiv

I'm looking for some converter LaTeX -> ConTeXt and perhaps LaTeX <- ConTeXt (just in case). I can write simple script and implement translation of basic syntax, but perhaps someone did it?

Comment: You can try pandoc, which can parse LaTeX and generate ConTeXt output.

Answer (score 2):

If pandoc conversion fits your need, then you can directly use it in ConTeXt using the [filter](https://github.com/adityam/filter) module:

```
\usemodule[filter]

\defineexternalfilter
    [latex]
    [
      filter={pandoc -f latex -t context -o \externalfilteroutputfile},
      output=\externalfilterbasefile.tex,
    ]

\starttext

\startlatex
  This is a \textbf{\LaTeX} document that includes a \emph{table}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    One & Two \\
    Three & Four \\
  \end{tabular}
\stoplatex
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Note that the conversion is not perfect because Pandoc's internal document model is not rich enough to store all LaTeX/ConTeXt documents.

Comment: Well, pandoc isn't perfect. Probably I need to write own script later.

Comment: Writing a parser for tex isn't easy. Have a look at xii.tex :-)

Comment: I have skills, but it is time consuming. And I'm not sure if I want to use ConTeXt, perhaps I will stick to LaTeX.